# Why the "if" didn't work ? (n queen problem)

Tags: c++, n-queens

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int k = 4;
vector<int> QLocation(k,0);
vector<vector<string> > board(k, vector<string>(k, "."));

bool check(int row, int column)
{
    if (row == 0) return true;

    for (int m = row - 1, n = 1; m >= 0; m--, n++)
    {
        if (board[m][column] == "Q") return false;
        if (column + n < n && board[m][column + n] == "Q") return false;
        if (column - n >= 0 && board[m][column - n] == "Q") return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void solve(int row, int column)
{
    for (int i = row; i < k;i++)
    {
        for (int j = column; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (check(i, j))
            {
                board[i][j] = "Q";
                QLocation[i] = j;
                break;
            }
            else
                board[i][j] = ".";

            if (j == k - 1)
            {
                i -= 1;
                j = QLocation[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{    
    solve(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            cout << board[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is infinite loop

I set breakpoints on lines 11, 15, 16, 17, and 28 to check the value change step by step

When i=2, j=1, enter the check and when m=1, n=1, board[m][column + n] == "Q" but does not return false
[image]

why?

====== 2021/08/25 22:00 update ======

when i delete these code and k=4

```
if (j == k - 1)
{
    i -= 1;
    j = QLocation[i];
}
```

the output is

```
Q...
..Q.
.Q..
....
```

when k=8 output is

```
Q.......
..Q.....
.Q......
.....Q..
.......Q
...Q....
........
....Q...
```

the third row always fail, but the other rows all correct

Comment: +1 for use of debugger. Can you please indicate which line the issue is on (such as by adding a code comment)?

Comment: Should `if (j == k - 1)` be setting the square to `.`?

Comment: `column + n < n` can be true only if `column` is negative, but I can't see that that ever happens.

Comment: @blackbrandt  in line 16
if (column + n < n && board[m][column + n] == "Q") return false;

At that time i=2, j=1, row=2, column=1, m=1, n=1, so
column + n <n = true
board[m][column + n] == "Q" = true
This should return false, but it is not actually executed

Comment: `if (row == 0) return true;` looks very odd. All squares on row zero are always available?

Comment: @molbdnilo
Because when row=0, it can be placed in any column, so I let him directly return true

Comment: Also, how do you get `1 + 1 < 1` to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This answer assumes you have corrected the typo in `if(column + n < n ...)` to `if(column + n < k ...)`

The problem is in this part

```
if(j == k-1){
   i -= 1;
   j = Qlocation[i];
}
```

consider the case of k = 4 and i = 2 in the iteration. The board will be looking like this at that point.

```
Q...
..Q.
....
....
```

and here `check(i, j)` is always false for i = 2, so `i` goes back to 1. But you are not changing the value of board[i][Qlocation[i]] back to '.'. This is one mistake(Even if you correct this, it won't work. I am gonna tell you why assuming you corrected that by adding board[i][j] = "." after j = Qlocation[i];). Now the values are i = 1, j = 3(j++ in for-loop). The check returns true, you place a queen there, and `i` increases to 2.

The board:

```
Q...
...Q
....
....
```

Here, check(i, j) returns true for j = 1. The board:

```
Q...
...Q
.Q..
....
```

Now i = 3. check(i, j) fails for all j. i decreases to 2 and j to 2(j = Qlocation(i), j++). check(i, j) fails for (2, 2) and (2, 3), on which point i further decreases to 1, and j to 4 (j = Qlocation(1), j++).

The board:

```
Q...
....
....
....
because of board[i][j] = ".";
```

Now j = 4 does not satisfy the condition j < k, so the inner for-loop breaks, and the outer for loop iterates to increase `i` to 2. check(i, j) return true for j = 1. The board:

```
Q...
....
.Q..
....
```

Now i = 3, check(i, j) fails for all j, i becomes 2. check(i, j) returns true for j = 3.The board:

```
Q...
....
...Q
....
```

Now again i = 3, check(i, j) returns true for j = 1. The final answer:

```
Q...
....
...Q
.Q..
```

which is wrong. So, you have to add a check whether the for loop exits without any Q in the row.

Comment: you are right, I have added board[i][j] = "." after j = QLocation[i];
But i still trying to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your issue I think is in this logic.

```
for (int m = row - 1, n = 1; m >= 0; m--, n++)
```

You are checking to see when `m` is equal to or more than 0. But you start at -1 and deduct 1 for every iteration. Which means you'll never stop unless returned.

And I'm guessing `m` for `board[m][column]` doesn't have `board[-10][5]` where it probably has `board[10][5]`. Sou you will never return false.

Comment: There is an early return for `row == 0`, so that's probably not what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

God... my eyes are broken. Although I checked it many times, I still didn't find the 16th line

```
if (column + n <n && board[m][column + n] == "Q") return false;
```

`column + n < n` should be changed to `column + n < k`

thanks to [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) and sorry for wasting everyone's time

====== 2021/08/26 00:05 update ======

I finally fix it, here is the code

(I know it's ugly and has exceptions (like k=3) and multiple solutions (like k=4 has two solutions) to deal with )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int k = 4;
vector<int> QLocation(k,0);
vector<vector<string> > board(k, vector<string>(k, "."));

bool check(int row, int column)
{
    if (row == 0) return true;

    for (int m = row - 1, n = 1; m >= 0; m--, n++)
    {
        if (board[m][column] == "Q") return false;
        if (column + n < k && board[m][column + n] == "Q") return false;
        if (column - n >= 0 && board[m][column - n] == "Q") return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void solve(int row, int column)
{
    bool rowFail = false;

    for (int i = row; i < k; i++)
    {
        for (int j = column; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (check(i, j))
            {
                board[i][j] = "Q";
                QLocation[i] = j;
                rowFail = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                board[i][j] = ".";
                rowFail = true;
            }
        }

        if (rowFail)
        {
            column = QLocation[i -= 1];
            board[i][column] = ".";
            i -= 1;
            column += 1;
        }
        else
            column = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{    
    solve(0, 0);
    for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < k; y++)
            cout << board[x][y];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```